# Prove that $(\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}, g_\mathcal{E})$ and the cylinder $((0,+\infty)\times S^{n-1}, dr^2+r^2g_\mathcal{E})$ are isometric

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

As in the title I want to prove that the $n$-dimensional puntunctured euclidean space: $$(\mathbb{R^n}\setminus\{0\}, g_\mathcal{E})$$
where $g_\mathcal{E}$ is the canonical metric induced by the euclidean on $\mathbb{R}^n$
and the $n-1$-dimensional cylinder: $$((0,+\infty)\times S^{n-1}, dr^2+r^2g_\mathcal{E})$$ where $dr^2$is the canonical euclidean metric on $(0,+\infty)$ and $g_\mathcal{E}$ the canonical one induced by $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $S^{n-1}$.

Given the specific metric on the cylinder (which is not the product one) I am trying to find an explicit isometry, but cannot succed.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you mean $+r^2 g_\mathcal{E}$ instead of $-r^2g_\mathcal{E}$?

Comment: Forget about the metric first. Do you know how a find a bijection $(0,\infty) \times S^{n-1}\to \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$? (Hint: polar coordinates)

Comment: @Arctic Char Of course is a +! Thanks. Yes I am trying to find a bijection first, and then I expect it will be an isometry. I come up only with  one which would work on the Euclidean space minus an axis though, a radial projection from the origin.

Comment: Which moreover has the problem that we have only the upper part of the cylinder actually.